# How to set query param to null with an ember action?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

In my Ember application I use query params to refresh model data and present new information. I have a use case that requires the ability to clear all the data and start with 'fresh' filters.

I'm attempting to create a 'reset' button in my ember application. This button should revert the existing query parameters in the URL to null.

The query parameters are configured on the route as follows:

```
export default Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    dateFrom: {refreshModel:true},
    dateTo: {refreshModel:true},
    hours: {refreshModel:true}
  }
}),
```

I tried the following action on the route and controller seperately:

```
resetParams() {
      this.set('queryParams.hours', null)
    }
```

I have also tried simply this.set('hours', null) but it doesn't make a difference. The Ember documentation doesn't discuss clearing the params, just stopping them from being sticky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `queryParams` are always present on the `controller`. So on the controller you have something like `queryParams: ['dateFrom', 'dateTo', 'hours']`. Then you can `directly do`controller.set('dateFrom', null)`to set the`queryParam`.

So on the route you can do `this.controller.set('dateFrom', null)`, and on the controller `this.set('dateFrom', null)`.

Its a bit confusing because the configuration for the `queryParams` is scattered over routes and controllers. However the *values* for the `queryParams` are always direct route properties. And *not* nester under a `queryParams` object. That is only the configuration.

Comment: That all makes sense.